# Options readonly vs nowrite

Tags: vimrc, buffers, save, options

Apologies if this is duplicate. I have searched and haven't found any related questions.

What is the difference between the options `readonly` and `nowrite`? The reference manual says:

- `readonly`: *If on, writes fail unless you use a '!'.  Protects you from
  accidentally overwriting a file.*
- `write`: *Allows writing files.  When not set, writing a file is not allowed.*

From these definitions, `readonly` and `nowrite` seem synonymous to me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The primary difference is that `readonly` is per-buffer and `write` is global to vim.

- `readonly` is generally used when editing specific files that you do not have access to write (like `/etc/fstab`).  Any buffer can be set to `readonly` if you want to prevent accidentally writing it to file.
- `nowrite` can be used to put vim into view-only mode, like pager utilities `more` or `less`, except temporary edits to the buffer are still allowed.

Comment: This makes sense. Thanks a lot!